# How can I make an automatic copy of a MySQL database to another MySQL database on the same server?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two MySQL databases called LIVE and REPORTS on the same server.

I want to copy the LIVE database and all its contents into the REPORTS database everyday at a specific time frame between 1 am and 5 am.

How could I do this manually and automatically?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/utils-task-clone-db.html

Comment: this question would probably get better answers at [dba.se].

Comment: Thanks. This is to make a manual copy. Can an automatic copy be done?

Comment: Sure, just use cron or other task scheduler available on your platform. For simple data copy you might even get away with MySQL [events](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/event-scheduler.html)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running a unix like OS , you can run a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) with [mysqldbcopy](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysqldbcopy.html):

```
crontab -e
```

Add your job :

```
30 2 * * * mysqldbcopy --source=user:pwd@localhost --destination=user:pwd@localhost source_database:cloned_database
```

This will run every day at 2:30 AM.

**Note:** Storing credentials in a crontab can result in them leaking to logs, mail, etc ...